# difference between boot receiver and broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, reboot

I am using an alarm manager and I haven't been able to maintain the alarms when the system reboots so, I have read that I should use a boot receiver which extends broadcastReceiver but I want to know the exact difference between the receiver itself and the boot receiver.

The onReceive method of my broadcastReceiver actually takes me to a new activity using an intent should i use this code and paste it in the onReceive of the bootReceiver? or what exactly should I write in the bootReceiver?

I am very confused about this point because I have multiple alarms and I have given each one a unique requestCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no separate entity "Boot Receiver" in Android. Boot receiver is just broadcast receiver which responds to intent with action android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED.

I believe you will need to do couple of things:

- Create a class which will inherit from BroadcastReceiver
- Add it to Manifest and add info that it should handle android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
- in onReceive code read all your alarms from persistent storage and set them again (so, they will be set again after each reboot).

P.S. I recommend to read through:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: Yeah I know that a boot receiver is just a class that extends a broadcast receiver but what I don't understand is that most of the people use two broadcast receivers one to handle the alarm and one to handle the reboot what I don't get is the reboot thing so, you said i should read the alarms from persistent storage so, I should save my alarms? how can I do that?

Comment: You can have one receiver which will receive a lot of different intents. It will work, but it only complicates the code. It's better to have two separate classes (one to handle alarms and one to handle reboot). I didn't do too much things with alarms. Per you question I understand that they don't survive reboot. If they don't then you have to implement some functionality to restore them and in such case you have to store them somewhere to restore from.

Comment: BTW. I recommend to try to break down big hairy questions to multiple simple questions and post them separately here. This will your chance of getting good answers increases a lot.

Comment: so, should I store them in shared preferences? as i said I have a unique requestCode for each alarm which is actually the row id of the item for which i need an alarm so, the shared preferences will have requestCode as the key and value would be the alarm? will that work?

Comment: @amateur programmer: Shared preferences should work fine for you.

Comment: It worked thanks all I did was save the time of the alarm when it was last called using System.currentTimeMillis() and the requestCode of the alarm in a sharedPreference and then retreived it in the boot receiver i.e. the other broadcastReceiver which had the android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED in it and one more thing I had to add a permission     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

Comment: @amateurprogrammer can you please give me full tutorial for doing that?

Comment: @MoustafaEL-Saghier I don't have a full example, however you can take a look at this: https://riptutorial.com/android/example/15019/broadcastreceiver-to-handle-boot-completed-events